# WSO2 ESB not returning payloads

Tags: wso2, wso2-esb

We're downgrading our ESB from 5.0.0 to 4.8.1 to match a different development environment and we've hit an unexpected snag: our APIs aren't returning anything.

We were originally using the  mediator, which I'm gathering was changed between 4.8.1 and 5.0.0 and cannot in the older version be used as a response so we switched to  This is a resource I have set up in an effort to get a smoke test up

```
<resource methods="GET" uri-template="/StaticTest">
  <inSequence>
     <log level="full"></log>
     <loopback></loopback>
  </inSequence>
  <outSequence>
     <log level="full"></log>
     <payloadFactory media-type="json">
        <format>{"asdf":"fdsa","blah":3}</format>
        <args></args>
     </payloadFactory>
     <respond></respond>
  </outSequence>
</resource>
```

I know the resource is being hit, because the logging statements make it into the logs. In fact, placing another  mediator over the respond tag will display the following

```
[2017-05-09 15:48:19,968]  INFO - LogMediator To: , 
MessageID: urn:uuid:6376072e-d005-497e-b7a1-9f89cff49099, 
Direction: response, 
Envelope: <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
    <soapenv:Envelope xmlns:soapenv="http://www.w3.org/2003/05/soap-envelope">
        <soapenv:Body>
            <jsonObject>
                <asdf>fdsa</asdf>
                <blah>3</blah>
            </jsonObject>
        </soapenv:Body>
    </soapenv:Envelope>
```

Which I have taken the liberty of formatting a bit. As you can see a soap envelope has been made matching my static JSON object, but SOAP UI is showing nothing. I get an HTTP 200, but no content. Any idea what could cause this?